Multi dependent drop downs in Word
I'm working on a Word VBA macro in Word and need some help with dynamically updating dropdown options based on user selections.
I have three dropdown form fields in the word:
One is the benefit category, the second one is benefit metrics, and the third is KPI.
There is a relationship between these three dropdowns:
For example: if I select Financial Growth value from the benefit metrics dropdown only Increase Earnings and Increase Revenue must be shown to be selected and if I select Increase Revenue, the Gross Dollars Earned must be displayed otherwise Net Dollars Earned can be selected.
I wrote the following code however it just works for only one set of dependent dropdown boxes and It does not work for the other set of dropdown boxes as their bookmark names change. For example, in the below picture only the first set of dependent dropdowns work and those that are in the second row don't work as expected.

Here is my code what should I change in this code to fulfill my needs:
The purpose of Module 1 is to push the value to the second dropdown box.
Module 1:
Sub PopulatedBenefitMetrics2nd()
Select Case ActiveDocument.FormFields("ddBenefit1").Result
Case "Financial Growth"
With ActiveDocument.FormFields("BenefitMetrics1").DropDown.ListEntries
.Clear
.Add "Increase Earnings"
.Add "Increase Revenue "
End With
Case "Financial Efficiency"
With ActiveDocument.FormFields("BenefitMetrics2").DropDown.ListEntries
.Clear
.Add "Expense Reduction"
.Add "Improve Financial Transparency"
.Add "Improve Profit Margins"
End With
End Select
End Sub

Here is Module 2: The purpose of this module is to push data to the third dropdown box.
Module 2:
Sub PopulateddKPI3rd()
Select Case ActiveDocument.FormFields("BenefitMetrics1").Result
Case "Increase Earnings"
With ActiveDocument.FormFields("ddKpi3rd").DropDown.ListEntries
.Clear
.Add "Net Dollars Earned"
End With
Case "Increase Revenue"
With ActiveDocument.FormFields("ddKpi3rd").DropDown.ListEntries
.Clear
.Add "Gross Dollars Earned"
 End With
 Case "Expense Reduction"
 With ActiveDocument.FormFields("ddKpi3rd").DropDown.ListEntries
.Clear
.Add "Expense Dollars Saved"
End With
Case "Improve Financial Transparency"
With ActiveDocument.FormFields("ddKpi3rd").DropDown.ListEntries
.Clear
.Add "Percentage of Cost That Can Be Allocated to Users, Stakeholder Survey Regarding 
Transparency, etc."
End With
Case "Improve Profit Margins"
With ActiveDocument.FormFields("ddKpi3rd").DropDown.ListEntries
.Clear
.Add "Dollars Made/Expenses Paid"
End With
End Select
End Sub


See: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/24661-help-cascading-dropdown-list.html#post77762
and, for multiple levels of dependency:
https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/24661-help-cascading-dropdown-list.html#post132696

Are there two BenefitMetrics dropdown fields?  BenefitMetrics1 and BenefitMetrics2 are in the first script. Is it a typo?

@taller yes ddBenefit1 push data to BenefitMetrics1 and BenefitMetrics1 push data to ddKpi3rd. also there is ddBenefit2 that should push data to BenefitMetrics2. Then when you select data the related one should be displayed to ddKpi3rd2.

There isn't any code which references FormFields("ddBenefit2") in your scripts.

@taller exactly I just defined it in the dropdown bookmark but I donot know how to change the code to read more than one bookmark to fullfill my need.

@taller this code is only works for one set of dependent dropdown not multiple one.
